# What does it mean when the output of an auto co-rrelation function is the unit impulse at t=0?

Tags: noise, signal-processing, noise-spectral-density

I read that auto-correlation function of white noise is unit impulse at t=0 is of strength N0/2. What does it mean that it is a unit impulse at t=0 ?

Comment: The main thing it tells you is that the input signal is aperiodic.

Comment: Auto correlation tells you how *similar* one part of the signal is to another part. For white noise, every part is supposed to be independent of any other section. If you took a sine wave, every section is same as a section \$n \times T\$ away. So the auto correlation will have peaks at every \$T\$. Having a peak *only* at \$t=0\$ means that any given section of the signal is similar *only* to that same section.